# Android - button random position weird behavior

Tags: android, button, random, setx

So I'm trying to appear 3 buttons on a random position. First im giving them a random position based on the screen size using this code:

```
    float x = new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels / 2);
    float y = new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels / 2);
    lbutton1.setX(x);
    lbutton1.setY(y);
    float x1 = new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels / 2);
    float y1 = new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels / 2);
    lbutton2.setX(x1);
    lbutton2.setY(y1);
    float x2 = new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels / 2);
    float y2 = new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels / 2);
    lbutton3.setX(x2);
    lbutton3.setY(y2);
```

Buttons at this point are set GONE in .xml file. When I trying to call their method so they become VISIBLE im doing it with using this code:

```
    lbutton1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lbutton2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    lbutton3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Problem is that while button1 appears in the position set by setX(x),setY(y), the other 2 buttons X position (from what i can tell) does not take the value of x1,x2 but it takes random values that I cant explain where they are taken from. All buttons Y position is ok..
Any ideas why could this be happening?

Comment: `View.GONE` by definition will completely remove the view instead of just hiding it.  I do believe that it is meant not to respond to view changed when in this state.  You should be using `View.INIVISIBLE` if you want them hidden but capable of updates if I am remembering correctly.

Comment: If GONE was the problem shouldn't I have it for lbutton1 too? This is the weird thing. lbutton1 works fine.. Also I just tried View.INVISIBLE but nothing changed

Comment: Basically setX and setY doesn't really work the way people thing it works. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411221/why-imageviews-getx-gety-setx-and-sety-do-not-represent-the-actual-value-in-t

Comment: @JaySnayder View.GONE makes View invisible plus this View doesn't take any space in layout anymore. but View is NOT removed, so you can change it, and then make vivible.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `activity_main.xml`.
Maybe you forgot to delete button's positioning attributes: `android:layout_below`, `android:layout_alignParentLeft`, `android:layout_alignParentStart` etc.
+ You should use `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: What layout do you use?

Comment: the buttons are on a linear layout

Comment: Try relative layout instead. Linear layout doesn't suit you

Comment: I think linear was the problem..I'm gonna test it and see if it works..Thanks man!