# ImageView incorrect X Y coordinates

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm having some trouble getting the correct coordinates(XY) for my `ImageView`.

My layout looks as follow:

```
<Relativelayout>
    <Relativelayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            //I want to get the X and Y of this imageview
            <ImageView/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </Relativelayout>
</Relativelayout>
```

After looking at a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17554835/5550161) question I implemented the following:

```
int[] img_coordinates = new int[2];
mImageView.getLocationOnScreen(img_coordinates);
double x = (double)img_coordinates[0];
double y = (double)img_coordinates[1];
```

Just to make sure, I added the above in a `ViewTreeObserver`, like this:

```
mImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int[] img_coordinates = new int[2];
            mImageView.getLocationOnScreen(img_coordinates);
            float x = (double)img_coordinates[0];
            float y = (double)img_coordinates[1];
    }
});
```

The problem I have is that the XY that gets returned are incorrect

---

**My question:**

Is there any reason why I'm getting incorrect coordinates and how can I get the correct ones?

---

**EDIT:**

I decided to provide my entire xml layout file with pastebin because it is very large and would take some time to format it in SO. [Here](https://pastebin.com/zR9TPwnb) is the link.

Also, here is a image of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: @pskink what answer are you referring to?

Comment: @pskink yes because it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I'm confused, here. Do you want the coordinates of the `ImageView` itself, or the touch event coordinates for a scaled `Bitmap` therein?

Comment: @MikeM. I want to coordinates of the ImageView itself.

Comment: @pskink You sure you linked the right post?

Comment: HB., how are the coordinates you're getting incorrect? That is, what are the values you're getting, and what are the expected values?

Comment: @pskink Yeah, I'm thinking they just want the `ImageView`'s (x,y).

Comment: @MikeM. I have 2 `ImageView`'s, for the question I just mentioned one to keep it simple. When I click a button I want to move one `ImageView` on-top of the other, by getting the XY of the target ImageView. Currently the image gets moved to the wrong position, not on-top of the other. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well, you can't do that inside a `LinearLayout`. It won't overlap its children, if that's what you mean by on top.

Comment: @MikeM. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @MikeM. I forgot to mention that the second imageview, that I want to move, is not inside the LinearLayout.

Comment: Oh, well, that's different. Whichever common ancestor `ViewGroup` they share will have to be one that allows overlapping children; e.g., a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. Then you'll need to base their coordinates off of their position within that ancestor.

Comment: This is all generalizations, 'cause it's not exactly clear what you mean to do. You probably wanna show us the actual layout, with both `ImageView`s in their respective spots

Comment: @MikeM. Please seem my ed, I provided a image of what I would like to achieve/do and a link to my .xml layout.

Comment: Well, honestly, there are easier ways to do this. Personally, I'd write a custom `View` for a game board like that. If you wanna stick with the available `View`s and `ViewGroup`s, though, you could greatly simplify your layout. For example, the main board could be done with 64 `ImageView`s in a single `GridLayout`. If you position that inside a root `RelativeLayout`, then add your piece `View` to that root, it'd be just a matter of setting the piece to the `GridLayout`'s offsets, plus the target's offsets; i.e., something like: `piece.setX(gridLayout.getX() + target.getX());`, and same for `Y`

Comment: @MikeM. That makes sense, I also think doing it like that will reduce my code. I will give that a try instead. Thank you for taking the time to reply.